# C: automatic error detection for MacLaurin Series & compare to the built-in sinx()

Tags: c

[Maclaurin Sin X Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0vnG.png)

so the main idea is to use (difference = builtin func - maclaurin func) and use the do..while loop to increment the N. So that it will continue incrementing the N until the minimum error satisfied. in this case i want the minimum error is 0.000001 so it will be `while(0.000001<=difference)`.

But the code i wrote didn't work as should be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
    
    int main() {
    
    
       int a, N=3;
       float sum, x, sumbuilt,difference;
    
       printf("enter x in degrees: ");
       scanf("%f", &x);
       x=x/180*3.14;
       
       printf("degrees in radian: %f ",x );
       
       do
       {
       sum=x; 
       int sign=-1; 
       float factorial=1;

       //sin x with maclaurin series
       for (a = 3; a <=N ; a+=2)
       {    
           float powersum= 1;
           for (int b=1; b<=a; b++)
            {
            powersum=powersum*(x);
            }
        
        factorial=factorial*a*(a-1);
        sum= sum + sign* powersum/ factorial;
        sign=sign*-1;
       }
       
       //sinx with built in function

       sumbuilt=sin(x);
       difference= sumbuilt-sum;
       N++;
       }

       while(0.000001<=difference)
        
       printf("\n sum: %f", sum);
       printf("\n sum from built: : %f", sumbuilt);
    
        
        return 0;
    }
```

as you can see, if i tried putting the input x=330, the output it gives is 4.235172 which is completely wrong. it should be -0.500147. Basically the "do while" thing i put inside didn't worked at all.

the output 4.235172 is the same output what i get if i put N=3 and without using the "do while" thing

i have no clue what i did wrong.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `difference` isn't defined and the `while` statement doesn't have a semicolon.

Comment: If you fix those problems, then `difference` can be large and negative which can result in your while loop terminating incorrectly. You also have problems that `factorial` and `powersum` can become very large, quickly making the terms very inaccurate and later overflowing float.

Comment: Rather than factorial and powersum, you can compute the next term in the power series from the previous one, by multiplying it by -x*x/a/(a-1).

Comment: wait, i accidentally forgot to define the difference in here, i did define the difference in my IDE and apologize, i still dont understand the solution you give

Comment: Is this some homework assignment? You may wish to read up on how to implement trigonometric functions numerically. The biggest gotcha to watch for: the practical solutions do not come from a calculus textbook. Numerical methods are based in calculus but aren't just trivial transcriptions from introductory theory into software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you fix the typos, you first have the bug that `difference` can be large and negative, so to check you are within the correct accuracy you need to take its absolute value. Next you have the problem that `factorial` quickly becomes too large to accurately be represented by a float (or even a double).

Instead of constructing `factorial` (a very large number) and `powersum` (which can also be a very large number), you can remember the last term you computed in the series, and get the next term by multiplying by -x^2 and dividing by the new terms in the factorial. This avoids huge numbers, at least for smallish values of x.

For example, if you've just computed `x^5/5!` then the next term is `x^5/5! * -1 * x^2 / (6*7)`.

Here's some example code that does this (hardcoded for 330 degrees):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double macsin(double x, int N) {
  double result = x;
  double last_term = x;
  for (int i = 3; i <= N; i += 2) {
    double term = -last_term * x * x / i / (i-1);
    result += term;
    last_term = term;
  }
  return result;
}


int main() {
  double degrees = 330;
  double radians = degrees * M_PI / 180;
  printf("%f degrees = %f radians\n", degrees, radians);
  double my_sin = 0;
  double std_sin = sin(radians);
  int N;
  for (N = 3; fabs(my_sin - std_sin) > 1e-6; N += 2) {
    my_sin = macsin(radians, N);
  }
  printf("stdlib sin = %f\n", std_sin);
  printf("maclaurin sin with N=%d = %f\n", N, my_sin);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solved. i was wondering about the `-x*x/a/(a-1)` thing. now i get it by changed it to `-x*x/a * 1/(a-1)`. Thanks for the help.